# Remove words from tuples after group by

Tags: scala

I have a list in such a form:

```
List( (a,1), (a,2), (a,3), (b,2), (b,4) )
```

I used group by

```
list.groupBy(x => x._1)
```

It resulted in a map:

```
Map(a->List((a,1), (a,2), (a,3)), b->List((b,2), (b,4)))
```

But I want the output as follows:

```
Map(a->List(1,2,3), b->List(2,4))
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala 2.13 introduced [`groupMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2018/06/13/scala-213-collections.html#groupmap)

```
list.groupMap(_._1)(_._2)   // res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(a -> List(1, 2, 3), b -> List(2, 4))
```

which is a succinct way of writing in Scala 2.12

```
list
  .groupBy { case (key, value) => key } 
  .mapValues { (values: List[(String, Int)]) => 
    values.map { case (key, value ) => value } 
  }
```

---

As a side-note, if you are new to Scala, consider the following beginner-friendly resources

- Real-time help: https://gitter.im/scala/scala
- Interactive exercises: https://www.scala-exercises.org
- Tour of Scala: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html
- Hello world template: `sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8`
- Online interactive playground: https://scastie.scala-lang.org